# How to add container div based on condition in ng-repeat?

Tags: angularjs

How to add div container based on certain condition in ng-repeat? Basically I want to divide main container into multiple sections. Here is the sample snippet of code:

```
<div class="content-wrapper">
      <div class="content"
           ng-repeat="metadata in $ctrl.pages"
           ng-class="metadata.page.title">
        <div class='page_section_title' ng-repeat="control in metadata.page.controls | orderBy:'sequence'">   

          //based on type of control - control.type, I want to divide controls into multiple sections - like
          //if(control.type === 'title'){
               <div class='page_title'>
                    <customControl control = 'control'..></customControl>
               </div>
          // } else {
                <div class='page_content'>
                    <customControl control = 'control'..></customControl>
               </div>
         // }
        </div>
      </div>

      <footer></footer>
    </div>
```

Here I want to create separate groups of controls by adding container div. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way is to use [**`ng-class`**](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass) to do the trick:

```
<div ng-class="{'page_title': control.type == 'title', 'page_content': control.type == 'content'}">
     <customControl control = 'control'..></customControl>
</div>
```

The interest of `ng-class` rather than `ng-if` is that you have only one `div` to declare.

---

In your full code:

```
<div class="content-wrapper">
  <div class="content" ng-repeat="metadata in $ctrl.pages">

    <div class='page_section_title' ng-repeat="control in metadata.page.controls | orderBy:'sequence'">
      <div ng-class="{'page_title': control.type == 'title', 'page_content': control.type == 'content'}">
        <customControl control='control' ..></customControl>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>

  <footer></footer>
</div>
```

---

[**Demo on JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/Mistalis/kuctmogb/)

Answer (score 2):

```
<div class="content-wrapper">
      <div class="content"
           ng-repeat="metadata in $ctrl.pages"
           ng-class="metadata.page.title">
        <div class='page_section_title' ng-repeat="control in metadata.page.controls | orderBy:'sequence'">   

          //based on type of control - control.type, I want to divide controls into multiple sections - like
          //if(control.type === 'title'){
               <div class='page_title' ng-if="control.type == 'title'">
                    <customControl control = 'control'..></customControl>
               </div>
          // } else {
                <div class='page_content' ng-if="control.type == 'content'">
                    <customControl control = 'control'..></customControl>
               </div>
         // }
        </div>
      </div>

      <footer></footer>
    </div>
```

Use ng-if to achieve what you desire.
Only when the condition is true, the container will get created, otherwise not.

syntax:

```
<element ng-if="expression"></element>
```

if 'expression' evaluates to true, element will be added to the DOM, otherwise it won't.

Comment: Thanks, but I want to divide "page_section_title" container into mainly two different sections/parts, on part contains "title" and other part should contain collection of multiple controls. I want something like "else{}" in "if(){}" statement.

Comment: You have mentioned if and else as comments in your question. If that is what you desire, ng-if will work as I suggested, like ng-if="control.type == 'title'" and ng-if="control.type == 'content'" . If you need something else, could be please explain.

Comment: Ok, say suppose you have a collection on objects in array, each object has property called type, objects could have different types(like, title, input, selections, separator, checkbox etc). The object with type property called 'title' should be added to one container having some class name, and any(remaining) objects other than type "title", should be added to another container having some class name.